# Trouble with Template Matching Function Overloads in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I'm currently working on a C++20 project where I need to implement a series of overloaded functions using template matching. I am trying to create a set of function templates that can distinguish between different categories of types (e.g., integral types, floating-point types, and custom classes) and handle each with a specialized algorithm.

However, I'm running into an issue where the compiler is not selecting the most specialized template overload as I expected. I've simplified my code to illustrate the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Overload for integral types
template<typename T>
requires std::is_integral_v<T>
void process(T value) {
    std::cout << "Integral: " << value << std::endl;
}

// Overload for floating-point types
template<typename T>
requires std::is_floating_point_v<T>
void process(T value) {
    std::cout << "Floating-point: " << value << std::endl;
}

// Overload for custom class
class MyCustomClass {};

template<>
void process<MyCustomClass>(MyCustomClass value) {
    std::cout << "MyCustomClass instance" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    process(10);        // Should call the integral overload
    process(3.14);      // Should call the floating-point overload
    process(MyCustomClass()); // Should call the custom class overload
}
```

When I compile this code with `g++ (GCC) 10.2.0`, I receive an error that suggests the compiler is unable to deduce the correct overload:

```
error: template-id ‘process’ for ‘void process(MyCustomClass)’ does not match any template declaration’
```

I'm looking for guidance on the following points:

1. Why is the compiler not selecting the correct overload for `MyCustomClass`?
2. Is there a better way to structure my function templates for such type-based overloading in C++20?
3. Could the issue be related to the concepts I'm using, or is it a problem with my function template specializations?

I've checked [CPPReference](https://en.cppreference.com/) and other Stack Overflow questions but haven't found a solution that resolves my issue. I'm compiling with the `-std=c++20` flag.

Comment: Don't specialize, overload.  `template<>
void process<MyCustomClass>(MyCustomClass value)` -> `void process(MyCustomClass value)`

Comment: This is a function template, not a class template. When you have an explicit signature, just make a plain overload without any template.

Comment: The actual problem is that you don't have a **primary template** in your code to explicitly specialize! So you can either add a primary template or just change  the explicit specialization to a non-template overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a **primary template** in your code to explicitly specialize!

This means that to resolve the error, you can either provide a primary template or change the explicit specialization to a **non-template overload.**

##### Method 1

Here we provide a **primary template** as shown below:

```
//added this primary template
template<typename T>
void process(T);

//other code as before
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MbPY8qsGb)

---

##### Method 2

Second way is to just provide an ordinary **non-template overload** instead of an explicit specialization:

```
//note the template<> has been removed from here
void process(MyCustomClass value) {
    std::cout << "MyCustomClass instance" << std::endl;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bKonnxYWY)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comment, when you have an explicit "specialization" for a function template, you just write a plain non-template overload:

```
void process(const MyCustomClass& object)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, if you have a template overload, be wary of perfect matches that can happen:

```
template< typename T >
void process(T&& obj) // generic implementation using perfect-forwarding
{
    // ...
    std::cout << "Generic template" << std::endl;
}
```

With the two overloads above, the following calls:

```
process(MyCustomClass{});

MyCustomClass obj{};
process(obj);
```

Will use the generic implementation and print `Generic template` because the template is a perfect match (for `MyCustomClass&&` <-- note the rvalue ref in the first case and for `MyCustomClass&` for the second).

To avoid that, you must disable your template for cv-ref combinations of your specialized types using e.g.:

```
template< typename T >
    requires(!std::is_same_v< MyCustomClass, std::remove_cvref_t< T > >)
void process(T&& obj)
{
    // ...
}
```